# Not able to display image from Oracle Blob using PHP

Tags: php, oracle, blob

In Oracle DB it shows (BLOB), using the above code to display the image but black screen is displayed.

Blob is stored via Java JDBC connection using setBinaryStream

---

**Code:**

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['serial_id'];
    $id1 = $_GET['serial_id1'];
    $id2 = $_GET['serial_id2'];
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM Mapping WHERE PRODUCT ='".$id1."' and (ID='".$id."' or VALUE='".$id2."')";
    echo $sql2;
    $array2 = oci_parse($conn, $sql2);
    oci_execute($array2,OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);

    //$result=oci_fetch_array($array2);
    $result = oci_fetch_assoc($array2);

    if (is_object($result['SCREENSHOT'])) { 
        $result11 = $result['SCREENSHOT']->load();
        header("Content-type: image/JPEG");
        echo $result11;                 
    }
?>
```

---

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: remove `echo $sql2;` from code

Comment: Removing echo $sql2;  it doesn't works

Comment: You need to provide more information... is there anything in the sourecode of the "image" (=> browser window) ? Is there anything in the error logs? What is the hexadecimal output from the database without content-type and conversion? Is your `is_object()` condition true?

Comment: is_object()  condition is true,  
In Error logs nothing specific to it.
hexadecimal output was trial purpose , i have removed it
In developer tools i see <img style="-webkit-user-select: none;" src="http://localhost:8012/View_image.php?serial_id=[BP]&amp;serial_id1=Adobe%20Portfolio&amp;serial_id2=uFollow%20us%20on%20Twitter%20and%20Medium%20to%20stay%20up%20to%20date%20on%20new%20themes,%20features%20and%20other%20announcements">

Comment: if i comment out header("Content-type: image/JPEG"); line from code , below string is displayed
)*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz����������������������������������������������������

Comment: Blob is stored via Java JDBC connection using setBinaryStream